# How to connect WPF GUI (buttons etc.) to methods of a class?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, user-interface

I have some beginner question.

Let's say I want to create some program that has a class `Ford` with nothing else inside than a property of type `string` named `Color`.

Now, I want to click a button thats located in main window which sets the property `Color` of some instance of this class to `"blue"`. There would also be a textbox displaying the current color.

I want to set a property of an object of class `Ford` that was previously created via

```
Ford fordFocus = new Ford();
```

My problem is - As soon as I write `focus`, Visual Studio instantly adds a curly red line under `focus`. It seems to me like the object is not created or cant be seen, out of scope, I don't know.

In other words, I know how to create a program which uses console for input and output, but i cant comprehend how create more or less the same thing with WPF GUI rather than a console. My ford example might be bad, if so please disregard and explain it in other way.

Its all WPF template VisualStudio 2015, MainWindow.cs:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        Ford focus = new Ford();
    }

    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        focus.Color = "Sky blue";
    }

}
```

whats inside class Ford:

```
private string _color;
public string Color
{
    get { return _color; }
    set { _color = value; }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: You need to update your question with code. It's wild guessing for us to figure out where you got stuck.

Comment: can we see your GUI or any thing you've done so far

Comment: take the (Ford fordFocus = new Ford(); from app.cs and place at top of the WIndow class that contains your button and it will be in scope

Comment: the reason I'm asking about `what you've done so far` is. Your question just went over my head specially that ford stuff

Comment: I still do not get what you are up to, can you please briefly explain what is that you want. what is that you want me to extract from This (http://prntscr.com/bajtb0) [ScreenShot]

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be, that you declared `focus` inside the constructor of `MainWindow` but try to use it inside another method - that means that `focus` is defined in another scope.

> ```
> public partial class MainWindow : Window
>   {
>     public MainWindow()
>     {
>       InitializeComponent();
>       // --- focus is declared HERE --- 
>       Ford focus = new Ford();
>     }  
>     private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
>     {
>       // -- Your try to use focus HERE --
>       focus.Color = "Sky blue";
>     }
>   }
> ```

You could add a field to your MainWindow that it can be accessed from within the constructor and from within the method.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  // -- DECLARE focus HERE
  private Ford focus;
  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    // --- focus can be CREATED HERE --- 
    this.focus = new Ford();
  }

  private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    // -- Now you can USE focus HERE --
    this.focus.Color = "Sky blue";
  }
}
```

You can find some useful information about scopes on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms973875.aspx)

Comment: Thanks! It works now. Im basically a beginner in C# and especially GUI. If i want to create an object that falls out of scope and gets destroyed at the end of program, i should create it in this place yes?